# How to prevent parent onclick from being invoked

Tags: jquery, events, preventdefault, stoppropagation

say i have a input

```
<a href="/somepage.html" id="somePage" onclick="actionTaken();"/>
```

Now i have attach additonal jquery event handler.

```
$("#somePage").click(function(event) {
    // this needs to be executed before the default "actionTaken();" event. 
    if (validationFail()) {
         // prevent the onclick event and link from going through.
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

It seems to me parent action are still being run.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to double-check that `validationFail` returns what you expect. You may also need to `return false` to prevent the link navigation, and/or remove other handlers that may have been assigned.

Comment: Can't you just call actionTaken within the click handler of your jQuery script, rather than having an inline event at all?

Comment: the actionTaken is some random code generated by JSF (javaserver faces)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run `unbind()` to remove previously assigned handlers (they are not parents, they are just other handlers):

```
$("#somePage").unbind("click");
$("#somePage").click(function(event) {
    // this needs to be executed before the default "actionTaken();" event. 
    if (validationFail()) {
         // prevent the onclick event and link from going through.
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that both the inline `onclick` and jQuery `click` event handlers fire at the same time when the link is clicked. You may consider nesting the `actionTaken` function within the `click` event handler like so:

```
function actionTaken(){
    ...
}

$('#somePage').click(function(e){
    if (validationFail() !== true){
        actionTaken();
    }
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Actually my answer is somewhat related to  Andrei

```
var somePage, handler;
somePage = $("#somePage");
if (somePage.length) {
    handler = somePage.prop("onclick");
    somePage.removeProp("onclick");
    somePage.click(function(event) {
        // this needs to be executed before the default "actionTaken();" event. 
         if (validationFail()) {
             // prevent the onclick event and link from going through.
             event.preventDefault();
             event.stopPropagation();
         }
    });
    somePage.click(handler);   
}
```